# java not found when ran from tcl shell

Tags: java, windows, tcl

I have 32 bit java 8 installed on windows 7 box
When I ran `java -version` from windows command prompt, I got:

C:\Users\Dcode>c:\Windows\System32\java.exe -version

java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode, sharing)

But when I run the same thing from tcl 8.6 shell, i got:

Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.6' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.[image: java error]

What is the probable cause. Why java 1.6 required for tcl? Kindly clarify

Comment: I don't know, but this sounds like a 32-bit/64-bit problem. Why running from Tcl's triggering it… no idea at all.

Comment: @DonalFellows no it doesn't. Why would you think that? Tcl simply says it requires 1.6. I suspect that check was designed to have *at least* 1.6 but does not accept 1.8 as a valid version for some reason.

Comment: @f1sh Tcl _really_ doesn't care about Java (except for when using Tcl/Java, which is something else entirely). It's just a program that it's running. I'm guessing that something in the environment or process configuration is making the Java launcher work in 32bit mode whereas Java 8 is just a 64bit installation. Which would be weird, but may be possible!

Comment: @Dcode: I see that you're using `//` in your Tcl code. Please try with just single `/` characters (it's _backslash_ — \ — that would need to be doubled): `exec c:/Windows/System32/java.exe -version`.

Comment: Earlier I was just having java8 (32 bit), when I got the error. Then I installed java6 and somehow it starts working :)

I am still confused that, if i was giving fully qualified name, then why there is ambiguity in behavior while firing from windows cmd prompt and tcl shell

And what's the dependency with java on TCL.

Actually the problem came when I was trying to trigger selenium jar from tcl, with the command:

java -jar "C:/Selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar"

Then I checked with java version, and found the above mentioned issue. 
@Donal Fellows: No issues with `//`